# Multi column query on Hbase

Tags: hbase

I have a customer table with customer ID as rowkey. I now have a requirement to query customer by fist name and last name. How can I scan table with both the columns in where clause using HBase Shell. 
I know how to do it for a single column.

Answer (score 0):

There are some filters that can be used during hbase scan ([value filter](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/ValueFilter.html))

see more [Scan HTable rows for specific column value using HBase shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013197/scan-htable-rows-for-specific-column-value-using-hbase-shell/36585239#36585239)