# How to query on hbase json string value

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am saving list of data as below in hbase with unique id along with column family name  :
[image]

I can query on address column family with specific id but I want to query on the json value like

where homenumber = 4

Can we do that? Any example will be helpful

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue, did you ever figure out how? I'm using a Java client though, but if you figure it out i can probably find a way to adapt it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use HBase filter for this. Find the possible duplicate questions

[Scan with filter using HBase shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256100/scan-with-filter-using-hbase-shell/35372338#35372338)

[Scan HTable rows for specific column value using HBase shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013197/scan-htable-rows-for-specific-column-value-using-hbase-shell)

To start working with HBase filter, refer

http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/client.filter.html

http://www.hadooptpoint.org/filters-in-hbase-shell/

Comment: those links works for key value column as I said above my value is itself a jsonString for which the key is address:someUnique id , I can fetch value based on id , what I m looking for is within value json search some data